# DataFrame select number values in particular locations to add comma (not to the whole column)

Tags: python

What I need is to convert number in a particular location to string with commas. My table has a column that stores different types of values.

[image: table/Dataframe view]

What I know is that if the Dataframe column (let's say, 'ColA') would have had all values of one type (i.e. integers) to which I wanted to add commas, I would have simply done this:

```
df.loc[:, "ColA"] = df["ColA"].map('{:,d}'.format)
```

But my question is if I want to change selectively, by specifying a location of a cell using iloc, then how can I add commas? In this case, I want to add comma only to value of column 'Value' for rows 1, 7 and 8.

Comment: I think you can actually do this in your spreadsheet? It's easier to do so

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ColA': [1234567]*9})
```

You can use mixed positional/label indexing and `update`:

```
df.update(df.loc[df.index[[1,7,8]], 'ColA'].map('{:,d}'.format))
print(df)
```

Output:

```
        ColA
0    1234567
1  1,234,567
2    1234567
3    1234567
4    1234567
5    1234567
6    1234567
7  1,234,567
8  1,234,567
```

Comment: thanks. I finally landed up using this:  df.update(df.loc[df.index[[1, 5, 8, 10, 20, 21, 22, 28, 37, 38, 42, 52, 54, 59, 60, 61, 63]], 'Value'].map('{:,.1f}'.format))

Answer (score 0):

I landed up using this to solve the issue. I did so since the numbers I was trying to add commas to were float type.

```
df.update(df.loc[df.index[[1, 5, 8, 10, 20, 21, 22, 28, 37, 38, 42, 52, 54, 59, 60, 61, 63]], 'Value'].map('{:,.1f}'.format))
```